# How to get month as integer in Visual Basic Script?

Tags: date, vbscript, monthcalendar

I'm trying to get the current month as a short string in a Visual Basic Script:

```
Dim month
Dim mth

month = Now.Month    ' This doesn't work.
month = Now().Month  ' Tried this too.
month = Month(Now)   ' Also tried this.

mth = MonthName(month, True)  ' (e.g. "Apr" or "Mar")
```

However, I keep getting runtime errors:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'Now'
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'Now()'
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch 'Month'
```

I'm able to use `Now` fine as a string:

```
CStr(Now)
```

Or as a plain value

```
Dim val
val = Now
```

How can I use `Now` as an Object for accessing its member functions?  Perhaps I am confusing Visual Basic functionality with VB Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Visual Basic Script is not case sensitive and my variable `month` was colliding with the built in `Month`.

Comment: I guess this harkens back to the original Basic implementations that were not case sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

VBScript Dates are not objects - use the Month(SomeDate) function to get the month **number** of SomeDate:

```
>> WScript.Echo Month(Now)
>>
4
```

To get the month's name (abreviated or full), use:

```
>> WScript.Echo MonthName(Month(Now()),False)
>> WScript.Echo MonthName(Month(Now()),True)
>>
April
Apr
```

(stolen from @collapsar, but using the correct (boolean) type of the second parameter).

Official Docs for 
Month(): [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eeeket2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)
MonthName(): [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58f13257%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

[The samples given are 'living' code, if you get errors, your code is to blame]

Comment: That also gets `That also gets Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch 'Month'`.

Comment: Do you have to somehow include the definition for `Month`?

Answer (score 2):

try this line of code:

```
MonthName(Month(Now()),1)
```

a standalone solution:

```
Dim imonth
Dim mth

imonth = Month(Now())   ' Also tried this.

mth = MonthName(Month(Now()))

WScript.Echo "mth = " & mth
WScript.Echo "mth_short = )" & MonthName(Month(Now()),1)
```

Comment: That also gets `Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch 'Month'`.

Comment: how dow you execute the code? `cscript //nologo <filename>` works fine with me (windows scripting host 5.8 on win7)

Comment: `cscript.exe MyCode.vbs SomeArg` on Windows 7 from a batch file (.bat).

Comment: it appears that you have to change your variable name `month` to some name that doesn't conflict with built-in functions, eg. `imonth`

Comment: So it is not case sensitive?

Comment: Wow, so I basically had the answer all along if it were only case sensitive!

Comment: basically yes. however, parentheses in function calls seem to be essential, too, even when there are no arguments, like for `Now()`.

Comment: @collapsar They are sometimes (check [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx)), but not in this case. `Now` works just fine without parentheses. The first 2 errors occurred because `Now` is a function that returns a `Date`, which is not an object and doesn't have a method or property `Month`. The third error occurred because he used `month` (which is the name of a function) on the left side of an assignment.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks, i stand corrected. fwiw, the article doesn't address the case of no args at all - at least the rules it lists do not apply, in the given code all instances of `Now` work with or w/o parentheses. nevertheless it's a worthwhile reading.

Answer (score 0):

As given [here](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_now.asp) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_month.asp)

Syntax:

```
Month(Now)
```